# After Update Trigger That Updates 3 columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I want to create a trigger that sets the load column as 1 (load column is default 1) and gets the current user and the current time in updated_at = getdate() and updated_by = system_user as the user updates any row in a table.

```
CREATE or alter TRIGGER update_testtrig ON test
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
UPDATE test set 
             updated_at = GETDATE(),
             updated_by = system_user
Update test set load_flag = 1

END
GO
```

but its showing error as

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Procedure tr_test, Line 4 [Batch Start Line 27]
> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: Your `UPDATE` statement has no `WHERE` clause, it's going to overwrite **every** row in your table. Consider using `UPDATE` with a `JOIN` on the implicit `inserted` table's key columns: e.g. `UPDATE ... FROM t INNER JOIN inserted AS i ON t.pk = i.pk`. That said, I don't think it's a good idea to implement audit-logging using triggers.

Comment: The error message said `tr_test`, what you have shown us is `update_testtrig` It is a different trigger. Anyway `update_testtrig` will not cause that `Subquery returned more than 1 value` error

Comment: There is no subquery in that query, so it can't produce that error. Maybe you have other `TRIGGER`s that are written poorly? Though that trigger makes little sense either, considering it doesn't reference the `inserted` or `deleted` pseudo tables.

Answer (score 0):

These are the triggers I use for the same purpose:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[trgMytableCreated]
ON [dbo].[Mytable] AFTER INSERT
AS
    UPDATE [dbo].[Mytable]
    SET [dbo].Mytable.[Created] = SYSDATETIME(),
       [dbo].Mytable.[CreatedBy] = CURRENT_USER
    FROM Inserted i
    WHERE i.ID = [dbo].Mytable.ID

CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[trgMytableModified]
ON [dbo].Mytable AFTER INSERT, UPDATE  
AS
    UPDATE [dbo].Mytable
    SET [dbo].Mytable.[LastUpdated] = SYSDATETIME(),
       [dbo].Mytable.[LastUpdatedBy] = CURRENT_USER
    FROM Inserted i
    WHERE i.ID = [dbo].Mytable.ID
```

One trigger for update of the **Created** timestamp when a new record is inserted and one trigger for the **LastUpdated** timestamp when a record is inserted or updated.

I also use **CURRENT_USER** for inserting the actual SQL user who's done the insertion/update.

Also, in your case the load_flag field can be set in the same statement. There's not need to do a separate UPDATE for this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[trgMytableCreated]
ON [dbo].[Mytable] AFTER INSERT
AS
    UPDATE [dbo].[Mytable]
    SET [dbo].Mytable.[Created] = SYSDATETIME(),
       [dbo].Mytable.[CreatedBy] = CURRENT_USER,
       [dbo].Mytable.[load_flag] = 1
    FROM Inserted i
    WHERE i.ID = [dbo].Mytable.ID
```